# Updating multiple columns - SQL & PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, loops

Imagine that I have 1 table named in `tblrooms` and the columns are

`id`
 `roomname` `capacity`

and has 3 data's, and inside my html code, there's a while loop to fetch the 3 data's. Then textbox will be thrice cause of the while loop. But i'm trying to update multiple data's using for loop in my php code, please help me out of this problem. I want to update the id's inside of the textboxes using for loop. And please let me know how to declare a variable with array.

Here's the code:

```
<form action="sample_server.php" method="post">
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "psbr");
$rooms = mysqly_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tblrooms");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rooms)) { ?>

<input type="text" name="text_id<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value = "<?php echo $row['id'];" ?>

<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

sample_server.php

```
for ($i=1; $i < isset($_POST['text_id']); $i++) { 
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE tblrooms SET capacity = capacity - 1 where id = {$i}");
}
```

Comment: Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: if its in core php, create a function and call the function where you want to update it.

Comment: What's the problem? You have three records being returned each with three fields. What do you intend to do with those three fields for each three records? Right now you are simply creating three textboxes for `id` one right after he other.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i don't know what you mean :( i'm a newbie btw huhu

Comment: "i'm trying to"...ok but what goes wrong? And... `where id = {$id}`...how and where is `$id` defined in this code? That could be related to the issue

Comment: @JNevill I want to update the id's inside of the textboxes.

Comment: you have a for loop that add 1 to $i each time but you never use it inside. Your query refers to $id. this is your issue

Comment: @LelioFaieta what should I do?

Comment: `$i < isset($_POST['text_id'])` makes no sense at all. `isset` returns `true` or `false`, not a number (to know this, you only have to check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), and also you don't have any $_POST variable called "text_id", you have maybe "text_id1", "text_id2" etc, but none called exactly "text_id". You need to get all the $_POST variables which _start with_ "text_id", and loop through them, getting the value from them.

Comment: @ADyson I already updated my question. I'm the guy has a problem on July 12 but the problem is still :(

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you can elaborate your question and add some brief code to your question.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I already updated my question.

Comment: @Script47 I think in this particular case he should be fairly safe as the ID is being generated internally by the program and not taken from user input, but yes as a general rule prepared statements are a better choice for a variety of reasons

Comment: @GordonM but it is user input which can be changed very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Read the syntax for MySQL's UPDATE command.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

You can update as many columns as you like in one statement using UPDATE.

Comment: True but I think OP has mistaken the terminology of "columns" for "rows" - if you look more carefully at the question, the issue is with looping through the POST variables and running the UPDATE multiple times with different values for different rows

Comment: Yeah, its really hard to know what he had in mind. Pointing him to the documentation never hurts tho...

Comment: I think you should learn all that you can.
Learn about how PHP deals with input.
Learn how the Database driver in PHP passes queries and parameters to the database.
Learn basic SQL. Once you have those skills, this task will not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems with this:

1) Your code `$i < isset($_POST['text_id'])` in the `for` makes no sense at all. isset returns true or false, not a number (to know this, you only have to check the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). So your loop will never work - comparing e.g. `1` to `false` or `true` to see which is less or greater is meaningless.

2) You don't have any `$_POST` variable called "text_id", so `$_POST['text_id']` will be empty. You have "text_id1", "text_id2" etc, but none called exactly "text_id". You need to get all the $_POST variables which *start with* "text_id", and loop through them, getting the value from them.

3) Using `$i` from your for loop as the parameter to your query is incorrect. There's no guarantee that your submitted textboxes start at ID 1, or even that they're in the same order. You need to use the actual value from the textbox instead.

Here's something which should work:

```
//loop through all the names of the POST variables
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key) 
{
  //use a Regular Expression to check whether the current field is one of the "text_id" fields
  if (preg_match("/text_id(\d+)/", $key, $matches)
  {
    //here we will use prepared statements and parameters to write the query safely, without being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.
    //first prepare the statement. ? indicates a space to be filled with a bound parameter
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "UPDATE tblrooms SET capacity = capacity - 1 where id = ?");
    //bind the parameter safely. $_POST[$key] will refer to the _value_ of the POST field we're currently looping over. In other words this will be the content of the textbox.
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST[$key]);
    //now execute the prepared query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
}
```

Here's some documentation regarding the functions and code structures I've used above, in case you haven't come across them before:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (foreach loop)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php (array_keys function)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php (Regular Expression matching function)

https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html (general guide to Regular Expressions)

http://bobby-tables.com/php (guide to writing SQL queries safely in PHP using prepared statements and parameters)

---

N.B. Once you've mastered this, for an extra challenge, work out how you can do the same thing by executing only one query - since you do the same operation on each ID, you can use a SQL `IN` clause to name all the IDs in the same query, i.e. `id IN (1,2,3)` instead of `id = 1`, `id = 2` etc in different queries. The challenge is to write the PHP which will build that query, and bind the correct number of parameters depending on what was submitted in the form! It's not too hard if you think carefully. And your code will be more efficient since it will always run exactly one UPDATE query, instead of several.

Comment: This answer is better suited as it actually outlines issues and gives viable advises and includes sample code using prepared statements.